# Svg circle is not completely visible in viewport

Tags: svg

this SVG:

```
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

shows only the bottom right hand side of the circle. Why is this? I expected the circle to be fully visible?

https://jsfiddle.net/b2gq1sf6/

Comment: Why would you expect it to be visible? Get a piece of paper, draw a circle on it centred on the top left corner of the paper. 3/4 of the circle will be drawn on the table and not on your paper.

Comment: I'd assumed svg worked like how I'd draw a circle on a piece of paper....by starting in top left corner of the paper and drawing a circle entirely on the paper - and not drawing in the table because that would be dumb

Comment: Computers are dumb, they do exactly what you tell them to do dumb or not. You want it all on the paper, draw it at cx=50, cy=50 and make the paper bigger too. cx and cy are the circle's centre.

Comment: Try `<circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>` Alternatively you may let the circle as it is and you change your SVG to: `<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" >`

Answer (score 0):

Since you give the coordinates (x,y) as (0,0) the circle's midpoint is positioned at (0,0) top left of the screen. You need to give (x,y) relative to the screen or whre you want your center of circle to be positioned. Since you give radius 50 the minimum width and height of the svg should be 100.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

Also look up about viewports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)